# Betta fish has become lethargic, his fins are ripped, and has some itching.

Tags: betta

So I've had my Betta for about 7 months now. He was doing great up until about a month ago. Now, this was the first ever time I had a Betta (or any pet for that matter) so I was a little late to realize there was something wrong. Basically, my Betta has become very lethargic recently; he has also been itching himself on the wall of the tanks, but the itching has gone down after treating the tank with Prazi Pro for 2 weeks; his fins are also ripped. I thought it was fun for but there are no white markings on the edge of the fins or tail. I tried treating the tank with kanaplex (separate from Prazi) but nothing really changed. I've been worrying and have no more ideas on what to do. Any help is much appreciated.